# How to scroll pixels inside html5 canvas?

Tags: actionscript-3, html5-canvas

I want to scroll (displacement each pixels) inside html5 canvas,
something similar to actionscript-3 BitmapData.scroll(x, y);

Comment: If you don't understand the question, that doesn't mean it is unclear question, others do understand, I got 2 answers, don't you know what dose "displacement" mean in Math?.. don't be self-centered minded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redraw the canvas to itself. The browser will internally do all the copying for you which is faster than doing it manually through JS, though the trick to make it work is to make sure the background is non-transparent (if alpha is required you will need to copy the content to a temporary canvas).

Then either clear the gap or redraw/fill it.

You can use this as:

```
//  BitmapData.scroll(x, y); 
->  scroll(ctx, x, y);
```

The core function here is a functional example of one way of doing this:

```
function scroll(ctx, x, y) {

  var ax = Math.abs(x),            // these makes our calculations
      ay = Math.abs(y);            // easier to do below...

  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';          // fill background for the left gap

  if (x < 0) {                     // moving to left?
    ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, ax, 0, w - ax, h,  0, 0, w - ax, h);
    ctx.fillRect(w-ax, 0, ax, h);  // or redraw something
  }
  else if (x > 0) {                // moving right?
    ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0, w - ax, h,  ax, 0, w - ax, h);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ax, h);
  }

  if (y < 0) {                     // moving up?
    ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, ay, w, h - ay,  0, 0, w, h - ay);
    ctx.fillRect(0, h - ay, 0, w, ay);  // or redraw something
  }
  else if (y > 0) {                // moving down?
    ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0, w, h - ay,  0, ay, w, h - ay);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, ay);
  }
}
```

The drawImage() takes an image source as first argument (image, video or canvas). The four next ones describes the region we want to copy. As we are gonna move pixels we don't need to include them in the region so we subtract those to increase performance.

The last four describes the destination region, which will be our new placement. It's important to keep the same dimensions as in the source region or the graphics will be stretched.

Working demo follows:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height,
    scrollX = -2,
    scrollY = 1;

// make background solid to start with:
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

// scrolls x in either direction (adopt same approach for y)
function scroll(ctx, x, y) {
  
  var ax = Math.abs(x),
      ay = Math.abs(y);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';          // fill background for gap
  
  if (x < 0) {                     // moving to left?
    ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, ax, 0, w - ax, h,  0, 0, w - ax, h);
    ctx.fillRect(w-ax, 0, ax, h);  // or redraw something
  }
  else if (x > 0) {                // moving right?
    ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0, w - ax, h,  ax, 0, w - ax, h);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ax, h);
  }

  if (y < 0) {                     // moving up?
    ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, ay, w, h - ay,  0, 0, w, h - ay);
    ctx.fillRect(0, h - ay, 0, w, ay);  // or redraw something
  }
  else if (y > 0) {                // moving down?
    ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0, w, h - ay,  0, ay, w, h - ay);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, ay);
  }
}

// ------ demo loop ----------------------------------------------------------
(function loop() {
    
  // draw some random points
  ctx.fillStyle = '#007';
  for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) ctx.fillRect(w-2, h * Math.random(), 2, 2);
  
  // use the scroll method
  scroll(ctx, scrollX, scrollY);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=180></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Take a snapshot of the canvas to another in-memory canvas:**

```
var tempCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
// canvas is a reference to your existing canvas
tempCanvas.width=canvas.width;
tempCanvas.height=canvas.height;
tempCtx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
```

**Create vars representing the accumulated scrollX and scrollY:**

```
var accumScrolledX=0;
var accumScrolledY=0;
```

**Then your `BitmapData.scroll(x,y)` becomes:**

```
function scroll(scrollByX,scrollByY){

    // increment the accumulated scrolling by the new scrolling
    accumScrolledX+=scrollByX;
    accumScrolledY+=scrollByY;

    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

    // redraw the canvas using the tempCanvas with the new accumulated scrolling
    ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,accumScrolledX,accumScrolledtY);

}
```

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var tempCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
var offsetX=0;
var offsetY=50;
var directionX=3;
tempCanvas.width=canvas.width;
tempCanvas.height=canvas.height;

var text="Scroll this text...";
ctx.font='18px verdana';
ctx.fillText(text,0,50);

var textWidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;

takeCanvasSnapshot();

animate();


function takeCanvasSnapshot(){
  tempCtx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
}

function scroll(scrollByX,scrollByY){
  offsetX+=scrollByX;
  offsetY+=scrollByY;
  if(offsetX<0 || offsetX>cw-textWidth){directionX*=-1;offsetX+=directionX;}
  ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,offsetX,offsetY);
}

var lastTime;
function animate(time){

  // timer stuff
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  if(!lastTime){lastTime=time;}
  if(time-lastTime<20){return;}
  lastTime=time;

  // clear canvas and redraw with scroll
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  scroll(directionX,0);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```