# I am drawing a real-time chart using React html canvas. The chart flashes when data is updated. is there any solution

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-canvas, real-time

If you run the code below, the chart graph will be updated while flashing. Is there any way to get rid of the glitter?
When the data changes, the value of the child changes, so it seems to be my rendering problem, but I don't know what format to change. Any help please

```js
import CanvasLine from '@components/CanvasLine';
import { memo, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const CHART_DUMMY_DATA2 = (): Array<number> => {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() - 249);
    return [...new Array(249)].map((_, _idx) => {
        return 0;
    });
};

const CanvasLineChartDemo = () => {
    const [chartHRArray, setChartHRArray] = useState(CHART_DUMMY_DATA2);
    const [chartSP02Array, setChartSP02Array] = useState(CHART_DUMMY_DATA2);
    const [chartRESPArray, setChartRESPArray] = useState(CHART_DUMMY_DATA2);

    const returnRandomFloat = (min: number, max: number) => {
        return (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(2);
    };

    const validate = () => {
        setChartHRArray((prevState: any) =>
            [...prevState, returnRandomFloat(-100, 100)].slice(1),
        );
        setChartSP02Array((prevState: any) =>
            [...prevState, returnRandomFloat(-100, 100)].slice(1),
        );
        setChartRESPArray((prevState: any) =>
            [...prevState, returnRandomFloat(-100, 100)].slice(1),
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            validate();
        }, 100);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, [connectStatus]);

    return (
        <>
            <div
                style={{ width: '700px', background: '#000', marginRight: 10 }}
            >
                vdrDevice {vdrDevice}
                <CanvasLine
                    height={50}
                    canvasData={chartHRArray}
                />
                <CanvasLine
                    height={50}
                    canvasData={chartSP02Array}
                />
                <CanvasLine
                    height={50}
                    canvasData={chartRESPArray}
                />
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
export default memo(CanvasLineChartDemo);
```

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';

type CanvasType = {
    yMin?: number;
    yMax?: number;
    height: number;
    lineColor: string;
    canvasData: number[];
};

const CanvasLine = ({
    yMax,
    yMin,
    height,
    lineColor,
    canvasData,
}: CanvasType) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
    let CanvasContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null = null;

    // Array Max number
    const getYMax = (data: number[]) => {
        return Math.max.apply(null, data);
    };
    // Array Min number
    const getYMin = (data: number[]) => {
        return Math.min.apply(null, data);
    };

    const calculateY = (
        canvasData: number[],
        index: number,
        height: number,
        yMaxNum: number,
        yMinNum: number,
    ) => {
        const xAxis = (yMaxNum / (yMaxNum - yMinNum)) * height;
        const yScale = -height / (yMaxNum - yMinNum);

        const valueRatio = canvasData[index] * yScale + xAxis; // 마이너스영역 및 플러스 영역
        return valueRatio;
    };

    const createCanvas = () => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        if (canvas) {
            canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
            canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
            canvas.style.width = '100%';
            canvas.style.height = `${height}px`;
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        createCanvas();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const yMaxNum = yMax ?? getYMax(canvasData);
        const yMinNum = yMin ?? getYMin(canvasData);

        if (canvas) {
            let xStep = canvas.width / canvasData.length,
                xAxis = xStep,
                xStart = 0,
                yAxis = calculateY(
                    canvasData,
                    0,
                    canvas.height,
                    yMinNum,
                    yMaxNum,
                );
            CanvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

            if (!canvas.hasChildNodes()) {
                CanvasContext?.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            } else {
                CanvasContext?.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }
            const canvasDraw = (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
                if (CanvasContext) {
                    CanvasContext?.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                    CanvasContext.lineWidth = 1.5;
                    CanvasContext.lineJoin = 'miter';
                    CanvasContext.beginPath();
                    CanvasContext.moveTo(xStart, yAxis);
                    CanvasContext.lineCap = 'round';
                    CanvasContext.strokeStyle = lineColor;
                    CanvasContext.fillStyle = lineColor;

                    for (let i = 1; i < canvasData.length; i++) {
                        yAxis = calculateY(
                            canvasData,
                            i,
                            canvas.height,
                            yMinNum,
                            yMaxNum,
                        );
                        CanvasContext.lineTo(xAxis, yAxis);
                        CanvasContext.moveTo(xAxis, yAxis);
                        xAxis = xAxis + xStep;
                    }

                    CanvasContext.stroke();
                    CanvasContext.fill();
                }
            };

            canvasDraw(canvas);
        }
    }, [canvasData]);

    return (
        <>
            <canvas id="canvas" style={{ width: '100%' }} ref={canvasRef} />
        </>
    );
};

export default React.memo(CanvasLine);

CanvasLine.defaultProps = {
    height: 50,
    lineColor: '#2C82C9',
    canvasData: [],
};
```

You can see that the chart line flickers finely.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvtTd.gif

If you look at the gif, you can find the sparkling phenomenon.
Please suggest a way to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.
`

Comment: _"If you look at the gif, you can find the sparkling phenomenon"_ - the GIF plays fine for me: I see no "sparkling" or flashing.

Comment: @Dai hello. Thank you for answer. If you check the gif, you can see that the chart line flickers finely.

Comment: I believe that might be because your `<canvas>`'s resolution is higher than the browser's rendering surface and your line-strokes are not aligned to the pixel-grid - though I don't know for certain.

Comment: BTW, your rendering code is somewhat inefficient because you're completely re-rendering all chart lines on every frame instead of [re-using the already-drawn lines and scrolling them to the right and adding new data to the left side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26869629/159145):

Comment: @Dai thank you I was able to get the keyword by hearing that it is somewhat inefficient in the part of re-rendering all chart lines.
It's not completely resolved, but progress has been made. Thanks to you I was able to solve it. thank you have a nice day